# C# WPF Convert a byte array into video file?

Tags: c#, wpf, video, arrays

I have a MPEG file which I have converted into a byte array. The intention is for a client to retrieve this byte array then save the MPEG file locally where it will be used in an WPF application.

I can convert the MPEG file to a byte array, but I don't know how to convert the byte array back to MPEG or save the byte array as an MPEG file.

How do I do this?

BTW any infomation about converting a byte array to any video format which WPF supports would be helpful.

Comment: An MPEG file __is__ a byte-array. It's  just on disk.

Comment: So, "I can convert the MPEG file to a byte array" - maybe show us how you do that.

Comment: Thats a very good point! I didn't test my code which converts from mpeg to byte array. And it isnt working! So how do I read the mpeg file into my own byte array within my function? Is this even possible?

Comment: The code which I have to convert any file to byte array isnt working when I give the function the path for the mpeg file. I am using the FileToByteArray function found here - http://www.digitalcoding.com/Code-Snippets/C-Sharp/C-Code-Snippet-Convert-file-to-byte-array.html . I receive an IOException when I try to use FileStream to open the mpeg file for reading.

Comment: "Configuration information could not be read from the domain controller, either because the machine is unavailable, or access has been denied.\r\n" --- Its my local machine, so should definately be available -- on the other hand, I have no idea why access to the file would be denied?!

Comment: What's the file path, and what's the stack trace?

Comment: Sorted it, file path was wrong. Cheers for your help.

Comment: Note that you can call `File.ReadAllBytes` instead of that function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes.aspx) to write a byte array to a file.

If the byte array contains a different format (eg, DivX), you'll need to transcode the file to MPEG, perhaps using ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

What about `System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(myFileName, mpegDataByteArray)`?